# Dynamic change of subject line in JavaMail.

Tags: linked-list, jakarta-mail, subject

I have a linkedList of emailes and a linkedlist of businesses. I send emails through JavaMail. 
I need each recepient to receive a separate subject line. For example:

> email1 - Special offer for [business 1].
>
> email2 - Special offer for [business 2].

Is it possible to do like that?

Comment: Yes, send each recipient their own separate message.  Why does that seem difficult?

Comment: Because I upload a bulk of email addedresses from csv file, click a button and send about 50 emails at once. I need differrent subjects (the end of the subject) for all of them.

Comment: You have to send each recipient their own separate Message, one at a time.  There's no magic that allows you to send one message and have it appear different for each recipient.